# How to catch this exception in promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, es6-promise, sweetalert

Consider the following code: particularly when "none" is selected. Using sweetalerts2

```
Swal.fire({ //
    html: '
    blah blah ',

    input: 'select',
    inputOptions: {
      'none': 'Please select an option:',
      'option1': 'First Option',
      'option2': 'Second Option'
    },
    inputValidator: function(value) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (value != 'none') {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject('You need to select an option');
        }
      });
    }
  }).then(function(theoption) {
      // etc etc...
```

On selecting "none", there is a javascript error. On firefox console, for example, I get
"uncaught exception: You need to select an option"
I realise that I am probably la hopeless Newbee

Answer (score 1):

When using sweetalert, you need to `resolve()` with the error message, not `reject()` the error message, thus, you need to change your `reject(...)` into:

```
resolve('You need to select an option');
```

See example below:

```js
Swal.fire({
  html: 'blah blah ',

  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    'none': 'Please select an option:',
    'option1': 'First Option',
    'option2': 'Second Option'
  },
  inputValidator: function(value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (value != 'none') {
        resolve();
      } else {
        resolve('You need to select an option');
      }
    });
  }
}).then(function(theoption) {
  if (theoption.value) {
    Swal.fire('Great!');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

See [documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-select) for further details.

Comment: What a terrible API. (A good answer, though.)